# How to read word docx in R with drop down form

Tags: r, docx

My initial file was created as a macro-enabled document with drop down list to fill some of the questions. I tried to read it into R with `readtext`, `textreadr` and `qdapTools` packages after saving it as a `docx` file. All of them can read it. However, the issue is only the answers filled with manual input appear in the R output, which are "FORMTEXT", and those filled with drop down list as "FORMDROPDOWN" do not appear. For example, I input family name manually, and selected sex = Male, and here is the output

```
Family Name:  FORMTEXT Larry
Sex:  FORMDROPDOWN
```

Is there any other package can read both manual input and drop down list?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to add a new DropDown item and I have been able to extract the value of the DropDown Item with the following code.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\empty_Word_File.docx"
doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

##########################
#### Add a form field ####
##########################
doc_Selection <- wordApp$Selection()
doc$FormFields()$Add(Range = doc_Selection$Range(), Type = 83) # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfieldtype
doc$FormFields(1)$Select()
obj_Form_Fields_One <- doc_Selection$FormFields(1)$DropDown()$ListEntries()

obj_Form_Fields_One$Add("Blue")
obj_Form_Fields_One$Add("Red")
obj_Form_Fields_One$Add("Black")

#############################################
#### Extract the value of the form field ####
#############################################
doc$FormFields(1)$Result()
[1] "Blue"
```